# Converting Column into Multiple Columns Using String Value in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble cleaning my dataset in R. I have a dataset with three variables(name, day,  data). The third variable actually contains all of my data but it needs to be parsed. I need to split this column into multiple columns based on a value in the column. For example, in the following database:

```
x <- data.frame("name" = c("John","John","John","John","John","Sarah","Sarah","Sarah"), "Day" = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2), "Data" = c("Map 28", 2,3,"Transfer","Time","Map 18",2,3))
```

which looks like:

```
 name Day     Data
1  John   1   Map 28
2  John   1        2
3  John   1        3
4  John   1 Transfer
5  John   1     Time
6 Sarah   2   Map 18
7 Sarah   2        2
8 Sarah   2        3
```

I need to look through the 'data' column and find any time the word 'map' is used, and then convert all of the data under that into another column. Like so:

```
  name Day   Data Val1 Val2     Val3 Val4
1  John   1 Map 28    2    3 Transfer Time
2 Sarah   2 Map 18    2    3     <NA> <NA>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

[EDIT]

Sorry all, I think I oversimplified my example... the issue is that each person on each day will have multiple "Map" values that need to be located. So it looks more like the following.

```
x <- data.frame("name" = c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John","John","Sarah","Sarah","Sarah","Sarah","Sarah","Sarah"), 
                "Day" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                "Data" = c("Map 28", 2,3,"Transfer","Time","Map 15",2,3,"Text","Map3",2,4,"Map 18",2,3,"Map 22",2,3))

    name Day     Data
1   John   1   Map 28
2   John   1        2
3   John   1        3
4   John   1 Transfer
5   John   1     Time
6   John   1   Map 15
7   John   1        2
8   John   1        3
9   John   1     Text
10  John   1     Map3
11  John   1        2
12  John   1        4
13 Sarah   2   Map 18
14 Sarah   2        2
15 Sarah   2        3
16 Sarah   2   Map 22
17 Sarah   2        2
18 Sarah   2        3
```

and then the final output would be...

```
y <- data.frame("name" = c("John","John","John","Sarah", "Sarah"), 
                "Day" =c(1,1,1,2,2), 
                "Data"= c("Map 28","Map 15","Map 3","Map 18","Map 22"), 
                "Val1" =c(2,2,2,2,2), 
                "Val2"=c(3,3,4,3,3), 
                "Val3"=c("Transfer","Text",NA,NA,NA), 
                "Val4"=c("Time",NA,NA,NA,NA))

name Day   Data Val1 Val2     Val3 Val4
1  John   1 Map 28    2    3 Transfer Time
2  John   1 Map 15    2    3     Text <NA>
3  John   1 Map 3    2    4     <NA> <NA>
4 Sarah   2 Map 18    2    3     <NA> <NA>
5 Sarah   2 Map 22    2    3     <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to get that fancy? This looks like a reshape from long-to-wide, using `name` and `Day` as identifiers for rows in the output dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I think I oversimplified the problem. Each person will have multiple Map values per day with varying amounts of data between each Map value. I have added edits to my original post. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `reshape` from base R after adding a `time` variable using `ave`

```
reshape(transform(x,time=ave(Day,Day,FUN=seq_along)),v.names="Data",dir="wide",idvar = "name")

   name Day Data.1 Data.2 Data.3   Data.4 Data.5
1  John   1 Map 28      2      3 Transfer   Time
6 Sarah   2 Map 18      2      3     <NA>   <NA>
```

with your new edit: Using base R you could do:

```
d = transform(x,ID=cumsum(grepl('Map',Data))->a,time=ave(a,a,FUN=seq_along))

reshape(d,v.names="Data",idvar = "ID",dir="wide")
    name Day ID Data.1 Data.2 Data.3   Data.4 Data.5
1   John   1  1 Map 28      2      3 Transfer   Time
6   John   1  2 Map 15      2      3     Text   <NA>
10  John   1  3   Map3      2      4     <NA>   <NA>
13 Sarah   2  4 Map 18      2      3     <NA>   <NA>
16 Sarah   2  5 Map 22      2      3     <NA>   <NA>
```

with tidyverse you could do:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 x%>%
   group_by(ID = cumsum(str_detect(Data,"Map")))%>%
   mutate(time=1:n())%>%
   spread(time,Data)
# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Groups:   ID [5]
  name    Day    ID `1`    `2`   `3`   `4`      `5`  
  <fct> <dbl> <int> <fct>  <fct> <fct> <fct>    <fct>
1 John      1     1 Map 28 2     3     Transfer Time 
2 John      1     2 Map 15 2     3     Text     NA   
3 John      1     3 Map3   2     4     NA       NA   
4 Sarah     2     4 Map 18 2     3     NA       NA   
5 Sarah     2     5 Map 22 2     3     NA       NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I think I oversimplified the problem. Each person will have multiple Map values per day with varying amounts of data between each Map value. I have added edits to my original post. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: @FredPoole if this answers your question you need to accept it as the answer. ie click on the tick sign beside the answer given. You can also upvote the answer

Comment: Sorry about that, first time asking a question on stack overflow.